# How to check microphone is already been use or not flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, audio, microphone

I am building a chat application in which I am sending voice messages. Now when I am calling or any other mobile app is using a microphone then my chat app voice record does not work. How I can check the status of the microphone in a flutter whether it's already in use or not. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can use this: https://pub.dev/packages/mic_stream

If the mic is being used by another service, it should throw an error (or undesired action).

Comment: I tried but didn't got any error while the microphone is use by other app.

Comment: @ArsalanUmer Hello! Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check flutter audio_session

```
interceptSession = await AudioSession.instance;
AudioSession.instance.then((audioSession) async {
  await audioSession.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration(
      avAudioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategory.playAndRecord));
});

await interceptSession.interceptSession.setActive(true);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_session) informs the operating system of the nature of your audio app (e.g. game, media player, assistant, etc.) and how your app will handle and initiate audio interruptions (e.g. phone call interruptions). It also provides access to all of the capabilities of AVAudioSession on iOS and AudioManager on Android, providing for discoverability and configuration of audio hardware.